# Find a $2$nd degree polynomial where $|f(5)| < |f'(5)| $ and passes through the origin

Tags: calculus

I'm unsure how to approach this question. I know that there will be no constant terms, but not sure about the other condition.

Comment: Any "2nd degree polynomial" is of the form $f(x)= ax^2+ bx+ c$.  As you say, "there will be no constant terms" so c= 0,  So $f(x)= ax^2+ bx$ and $f'(x)= 2ax+ b$.  f(5)= 25a+ 4b and f'(5)= 10a+ b.  The condition that |f(5)|< |f'(5)| is |25a+ 4b|< |10a+ b|.  That gives *either* 25a+ 4b< 10a+ b *or* 25a+ 4b< -10a- b.   There are infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = ax^2 + bx$, $f'(x) = 2 a x + b$. We have $f(5) = 25a + 5b$ and $f'(5) = 10a + b$. We require $|25a + 5b| < |10a + b|$. The only other requirement I see is that $ab \neq0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  write the polynomial as $f(x)=ax^2+bx$.  As you say, the constant term has to be zero.  What is $f(5)?$  What is $f'(5)?$  How small can you make $|f(5)|?$  That is likely to be smaller than $|f'(5)|$  You were just asked for one polynomial, not a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

Start with $ax^2+bx$.

You need $|25a+5b|<|10a+b|$

Take $b=-5a$ woth non-zero values.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$ f(x)=ax^2+bx. $$
Then from $|f(5)|<|f'(5)|$, you have
$$|25a+5b|<|10a+b|$$
and hence
$$ 25(25a^2+10ab+b^2)<100a^2+20ab+b^2.$$
So
$$ 525a^2+230ab+24b^2<0 $$
from which one has
$$ a>-\frac{6}{35}b \text{ or }a<-\frac{4}{15}b. $$
Thus if $a>-\frac{6}{35}b$ or $a<-\frac{4}{15}b$, one has $|f(5)|<|f'(5)|$.